# SQL: is this possible for a pair-wise comparison

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have a table named USER and I have 3 columns `user_name`, `user_password` and `user_surname`, with `user_name` and `user_password` set as the primary key. When a user log into the program they are required to enter there name and password.

Now I need to verify this combination, so I need to know if I can do pair-wise comparison like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE (user_name, user_password) = ('&name', '&password');
```

I know that you can use pair-wise comparison like the above with a IN but do not know if you can use it with =. The thing is that the user needs to enter the two values (name, password) and then it needed to be checked in the table.

Please I need advice

Comment: What database?  Support for tuple comparisons varies.

Comment: Sorry I have to ask WHY is user_name and password part of the primary key?  user_name should be enough; if its not then you run the risk of having some logic problems later: For example: Joe creates user1 with pwd 1234 and has lots of data he likes stored in the database.  Jane comes along and creates user1 with password 1234 and gets a duplicate key vilation.  Jane then logs in with user1 with pasword 1234 and starts downloading all of Joes data...  So much for security.

Comment: The thing is if I use only name, as the primary key, then there is a bigger chance of having a key violation as there might be 2 people with the same name what then? I was also worried about this as I tried to look for a value that would be unique to each person like a cellphone number or ID number, but some of the users for which the program is intented might not have either of the two.

Comment: @Japster that's why people create artificial usernames to identify users: you can ensure that the name is unique when it's created.  If you have a user called Able Baker you can give the user name able.baker; when a new one turns up with the same name, you can give the user name able.baker2.  (Many sites use an alternative approach by identifying users through their e-mail addresses.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In T-Sql, we use

```
Select * 
From User 
Where User_Name = @Uname AND Password = @Passwd
```

Your sort of comparison is not possible , I think.

Since you are using Access

```
Select * 
From User 
Where User_Name = ? AND Password = ?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know how to use the variables with an Access database, since Im still a student and use to Oracle. So you answered 2 questions in one :-D

Comment: You can also use named parameters in Access: `select * from User where User_Name = par_user_name and Password = par_password`.  Jet just assumes that any identifier it can't otherwise resolve is a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
SELECT *
    FROM user
    WHERE user_name = '&name'
        AND user_password = '&password';
```

Comment: I will be using an access database.

Comment: @Japster: and you cannot do this in Access?? That's the most basic SQL, really....

Comment: I just wanted to know about the pairwise and using the ( ) instead of the AND

Answer (score 0):

Try it with your database, if it does not work just use

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = '&name' AND user_password = '&password'
```

Comment: So by using the AND it is the same as using the pairwise comparison?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = '&name' AND user_password = '&password'=;
```